# Stop timers in deleted JavaScript scripts

Tags: javascript, html, timer, intervals

I have a simple HTML code with two buttons. When one button is pressed, a timer is started. This timer is located in a script that normally would be retreived with JQuery.

Then we have another button, that would delete (clear) the script. Unfortunaly the timer remains resident. I do receive an error when i try to delete the script twice, but i can start multiple timers even when the script was removed.

```
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="StartTimer();" >Start Timer</button>
<button onclick="DeleteScript();" >Stop Timer</button>
<script>
 function DeleteScript()
 {
    document.scripts.flexiblesource.remove();
 }

</script>

<script id="flexiblesource">
 var intervalId;
 function DoThis()
        {
            console.log("Doing it...");
        }

  function StartTimer()
        {
             intervalId = window.setInterval(
                function()
                {
                    DoThis();
                }
                , 1000);
        }
        
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I was expecting the timers also to be "destroyed".

Comment: Deleting a `<script>` element does not change what the script code did to the DOM (etc), as you have discovered. It is not a useful thing to do. Your script saves the timer id in a global variable, so you can `clearInterval(intervalId)` to stop it.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than removing the script, use `clearInterval()` function. it will stop the `setInterval()` function.

Please refer the `clearInterval()` function [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearInterval).

```html
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="StartTimer();" >Start Timer</button>
<button onclick="DeleteScript();" >Stop Timer</button>
<script>
         var intervalId;
         function DeleteScript()
         {
            window.clearInterval(intervalId);
         }

        function DoThis()
        {
            console.log("Doing it...");
        }

        function StartTimer()
        {
             intervalId = window.setInterval(
                function()
                {
                    DoThis();
                }
                , 1000);
        }
        
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your function to remove the script call the `clearInterval` function before removing the script from the page - as:

```js
function DeleteScript() {
  if( !isNaN(intervalId) )clearInterval( intervalId );
  document.scripts.flexiblesource.remove();
  console.log('#ok#')
}
```

```html
<button onclick="StartTimer();">Start Timer</button>
<button onclick="DeleteScript();">Stop Timer</button>

<script id='flexiblesource'>
  var intervalId;
  var i=1;

  function DoThis() {
    console.clear();
    console.log(`Doing it...${i}`);
    i++;
  }

  function StartTimer() {
    intervalId = window.setInterval(
      function() {
        DoThis();
      }, 1000);
  }
</script>
```